# Употребление кавычек при несогласии

Tags: кавычки

Последнее время часто сталкиваюсь с тем, как кто-то высказывается, используя определённые выражения (допустим, речь идёт о несолидности чьего-то поступка), а потом другой человек, который не согласен с первым одним или несколькими людьми, говорит что-то такое:

*Народ тут уже испереживался из-за "несолидности" его поступка* и пр.

То есть тот, кто не согласен с этим выражением, заключает его в кавычки. ***Это правильно и, если да, то чем можно обосновать?***

Есть реальный пример, но не хочу его приводить за спиной автора, может, он против будет.

Comment: Кавычками выделяются <...> слова, сказанные иронически: …Мы в литературе чтим  «табель о рангах»  и боимся говорить вслух о  «высоких персонах» (Бел.); А новый  «родственник»  оказался просто проходимцем; От  «бумов»  и спадов — к постоянному кризису https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827548.html

Comment: Да видел я. А такие можно отнести к ироническим?

Comment: @slava1947: ответите?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: А такие можно отнести к ироническим?_ === Ну, если они были произнесены с соответствующей иронии интонацией, то можно. Ну а если есть сомнения в возможности ссылки на этот пункт из Розенталя, можно вспомнить следующий: (Кавычками выделяются) _...6) слова из чужого текста._

Comment: @slava1947: точно! Спасибо большое!

Comment: И всё-таки в моём случае, наверно, действительно была ирония. Вот только в данном случае я её вроде разделяю, а когда нет, мне как раз поэтому и кажутся неуместными кавычки. Кстати, а с чужим текстом там ни одного примера нету на одно слово.